# How to install a shower pan drain with this non-standard drainage pipe?

Tags: shower, drain, pipe-fitting, old-pipes

I'm installing a shower pan ([this one](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/glacier-bay-60-inch-x-32-inch-acrylic-shower-base-with-right-concealed-drain/1001186709), to be exact) into my condo unit, but I don't think the drain pipe is a standard size. It's a metal pipe, here are some photos of it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I measured the pipe to be 1-11/16" (inside diameter) and it looks like most metal pipes come in 1/4" increments, so I'm not sure what my best course of action is here. I'm guessing I'll need to get the closest size down (1-3/4") and weld it onto the drain pipe, and then buy a shower drain that can connect to the metal pipe (or use a rubber gasket which is squeezed around the pipe) for the drain on the shower pan.

Also somewhat related—the top of the metal pipe was connected to the overflow drain on the tub that used to be there (I assume). Is there an easy way to cap that off as well?

Comment: Looks like you have some serious wall repair to do as well with the metal studding rusted out like that.

Comment: As far as i know, plumbing pipes are measured as outside diameter. I would double check that a standard one won't fit.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Oh yeah they look awful, I will be removing those metal studs/tracks and buying new ones.

Comment: @RohitGupta Good catch, you're right, it seems the diameter from the outside is 1-3/4", I'll update my main post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you have there is a bronze or brass slip fitting housing, lacking its matching nuts and compression washers to make it take standard **slip fit trap** parts, such as the drain and overflow of the tub that was here. Modern versions of this part can still be had for a lot of money, but Polypropylene has largely replaced them. If you were putting a tub here you could buy replacement nuts and compression washers.

It's a standard size, but not a standard *drain pipe* size, because it's not one. It will join to a standard drain pipe at some point, possibly right at the bottom of the Tee. Of course, that might be sweated (soldered) copper drain pipe in keeping with the bronze fitting that's showing.

To install a shower drain here, you'll be removing this fitting.